# Citrus simulator how to send and receive java object in different queue

Tags: spring-jms, citrus-framework

I'm trying to set up a simulator. I want to receive objects "MORequest" in one queue - "citrus_1". And send MOResponse to the "citrus_2" queue.
In the configuration class, I wrote the following:

@Configuration
public class SimulatorJmsConfig extends SimulatorJmsAdapter {

```
@Value("${tqa.jms.morquest.endpoint}")
private String morequestDestinationName;

@Value("${tqa.jms.broker.uri}")
private String glassfishJmsBrokerUri;

@Bean(name = "tqa.jms.broker.uri")
public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new QueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        connectionFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList,
                glassfishJmsBrokerUri);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connectionFactory;
}
@Bean
public JmsEndpoint jmsOutboundEndpoint() {
    return CitrusEndpoints.jms()
            .synchronous()
            .connectionFactory(connectionFactory())
            .destination("citrus_2")
            .build();
}}
```

In "application.properties" I registered the queue listened to by the simulator:

```
citrus.simulator.jms.inboundDestination = citrus_1
citrus.simulator.jms.enabled=true
```

My default scenario class:

```
enter code here@Scenario("JMS_SEND")public class DefaultScenario extends AbstractSimulatorScenario {@Autowired JmsEndpointjmsOutboundEndpoint;@Override public void run(ScenarioDesigner scenario){scenario.receive();scenario.send(jmsOutboundEndpoint).payload("TestMessage");}}
```

In the logs I see how my turn is listening:

```
2018-07-10 12:08:38.455 DEBUG 728 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] javax.jms.session                        : Session created: ConnectionID=8889371755234545920, SessionID=88893717552346042882018-07-10 12:08:38.456 DEBUG 728 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate   : Executing callback on JMS Session: ConnectionID=8889371755234545920, SessionID=88893717552346042882018-07-10 12:08:38.464 DEBUG 728 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] javax.jms.session:Message consumer created: ConnectionID=8889371755234545920, SessionID=8889371755234604288, ConsumerID=8889371755234606592, DestName=citrus_1
```

So ...  when I send my Object in queue "citrus_1" in logs i see few exeptions:

```
2018-07-10 14:13:05.060 DEBUG 15928 --- [enario:JMS_SEND] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.consol.citrus.simulator.model.ScenarioExecution{executionId=1, endDate=Tue Jul 10 14:13:05 MSK 2018, scenarioParameters=<uninitialized>, errorMessage=com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Could not find proper message validator for message type 'XML', please define a capable message validator for this message type
at com.consol.citrus.validation.MessageValidatorRegistry.findMessageValidators(MessageValidatorRegistry.java:83)
```

and

```
2018-07-10 14:13:05.072 ERROR 15928 --- [enario:JMS_SEND] c.consol.citrus.report.LoggingReporter   : TEST FAILED ScenarioDesigner <com.consol.citrus.simulator.scenario> Nested exception is:com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Could not find proper message validator for message type 'XML', please define a capable message validator for this message typeat com.consol.citrus.validation.MessageValidatorRegistry.findMessageValidators(MessageValidatorRegistry.java:83)~[citrus-core-2.7.3.jar:na
```

and main exeption:

```
2018-07-10 14:13:10.889 ERROR 15928 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] c.c.c.s.e.SimulatorEndpointPoller:Failed to process message: Failed to get correlationkeyfor'citrus_message_correlator_simulatorJmsInboundEndpoint:consumer'2018-07-10 14:13:10.889 DEBUG 15928 ---[cTaskExecutor-1]c.c.c.s.e.SimulatorEndpointPoller:Failed to get correlationkey for 'citrus_message_correlator_simulatorJmsInboundEndpoint:consumer'com.consol.cit
```

Why is this happening? How to send an object?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you receive an object message and Citrus does not know how to auto pick the validation mechanism for this message payload. You do not give any expected payload information and Citrus is not able to auto guess what message payload validation type to use.

The default message type is XML. This is why Citrus tries to use XML message payload validation and this is failing for the object payload.

I suggest to use a [validation matcher](https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/2.7.6/html/index.html#java-dsl-validation-callbacks) on your very first `scenario.receive()` operation. With this you are explicitly adding a validation for the received object payload. As an alternative to that you could explicitly set the message type to `plaintext` and use the expected message payload such as `@ignore@`.